# how to disable able alerts if its not needed(critical level)

Tags: c#

```
void DisplayLowQuantityItems()
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("Select Brand from Tires where Quantity <5",con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    StringBuilder productNames= new StringBuilder();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        productNames.Append(reader["Brand"].ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
    }
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Following Products quantity is lessthan 5\n"+productNames);
}
```

how can i disable this if there's no item in less than 5?

it keeps showing even there's no less than 5
thanks for the help

Comment: Use a counter, set it to 0, and increment it inside your `while`, loop. At the end of code before showing `MessageBox`, use a check, `if(counter < 5)`

Comment: @adv12, `productNames` is a `StringBuilder`, I don't know how count will work, I guess, the OP has to split and then check length or something

Comment: @Habib, oops I skimmed.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void DisplayLowQuantityItems() 
{
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("Select Brand from Tires where Quantity <5",con);
  con.Open();
  SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
  StringBuilder productNames= new StringBuilder();
  int count = 0;
  while(reader.Read())
  {
      productNames.Append(reader["Brand"].ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
      count++;
  }
  con.Close();
  if (count == 0)
  {
       //leave it blank
  }
  else
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Following Products quantity is lessthan 5\n"+productNames);
  }
}
```

Your question, is to disable this alert right? then this should be the answer :)

Comment: Yes, wow, its been so long since i post this. so its in count of == 0 not <5 , ok ok. GREAT (y)

Comment: Yeah. now it can disable

Answer (score 1):

Take a `counter` variable and increment it in the loop,

```
int counter=0;
while(reader.Read())
    {
      productNames.Append(reader["Brand"].ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
      counter++;
    }
if(counter<5)
    MessageBox.Show("Following Products quantity is lessthan 5\n"+productNames);
```

another thing you can do is to save all the stuff in a **DataTable** and use it's **Count** Property

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
con.close();
if (dt.Rows.Count < 5)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

your code will be as:

```
void DisplayLowQuantityItems()
{
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("Select Brand from Tires where Quantity <5",con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
StringBuilder productNames= new StringBuilder();
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
con.Close();

if(dt.Rows.Count>=5)
{
    productNames.Append(reader["Brand"].ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Following Products quantity is lessthan 5\n"+productNames);
}
}
```

Comment: //do stuff... please make it clear, is that where i should put MessageBox?

Comment: Yes,,, Here You can Place the MessageBox

Comment: but... my question is still not answered T_T "how to disable able alerts if its not needed"

Comment: bro, it will not be viewed if you have records more than 5

Comment: i replace the if (counter<5) by that Datatable...but it still appearing even my item's quantity is more than 5...

Comment: bro, Let me re-phrase all your code in another context, check the edited one after a 2 or 3 minutes

Comment: @JelNo you can check it now

Comment: its still appearing, but now when i have lower than 5, the brand wont show :(